# How to delete the cell from python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete the dataframe index value specific like in 11th row 80 value using python dataframe pandas. I want to delete the value at the 11th row column no. of clients 86. I want to delete specific 86 only not row or column using python.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'delete' means 'set to zero', then you can set the value in column 'No_Of_Clients' of row with index 11 by

```
df.at[11, 'No_Of_Clients'] = 0
```

Alternatively, you can also set it to `None` or `np.nan` depending on your needs.