# How to move value to another columns by if else condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to move the column value to another column depending on the condition.

In the table below, if column A is 4 or more, the value of A1_1 is moved to A1_3, if the value is 3, it is moved to A1_2, and if the value is less than 2, the value is kept in A1_1.
I want to apply the same logic to columns B, B_1, B1_2, and B1_3.
How to approach it?

[image]

A   B   A1_1    A1_2    A1_3    B1_1    B1_2    B1_3
1   1   Apple           Apple
2   2   Banana          Banana
3   3   Tomato          Tomato
4   4   Apple           Apple
5   5   Banana          Banana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over your Dataframe and easily apply this logic :

```py
import numpy as np
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A']>=4:
        row['A1_3']=row['A1_1']
        df.at[index,'A1_1']=np.nan
    elif row['A']==3:
        row['A1_2']=row['A1_1']
        df.at[index,'A1_1']=np.nan
```

- `df.iterrows()` return `index` and `row` in each iteration. `index` is index of row and `row` is entire row which you can access each cell by `row['Name_Of_Column']`
- according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862698/how-to-delete-the-cell-from-python-pandas-dataframe) answer you can replace `np.nan` with `None` or `0` depend on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.apply(axis=1)` to iterate through each row and `move` the columns as you deem fit.

```
def update_row(row):
    col = 'A_1'
    if(row['A']>3):
        col='A_3'
    elif(row['A']==3):
        col='A_2'

    # Set A_1 to empty string and move the value to the required column
    a1_val = row['A_1']
    row['A_1'] = ""
    row[col] = a1_val
    
    return row

df.apply(lambda x: update_row(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbling upon this question, here is a vectorial approach using reshaping that doesn't rely on `iterrows`/`apply` and that should be generic for any number of conditions

```
import numpy as np

# this part is to be defined by the user
bins = [0, 3, 4, np.inf]       # boundaries for each condition
labels = ['1_1', '1_2', '1_3'] # suffix to use for each interval
                               # 0-3 -> 1_1 ; 3-4 -> 1_2 ; >4 -> 1_3
ref_cols = ['A', 'B']

# this part is automatic
# reshape to long form
tmp = df.melt(ref_cols)
# extract the reference column id and the variable part
parts = tmp['variable'].str.extract('([A-Z])(.*)')

# create the new column name based on the rules
idx, cols = pd.factorize(parts[0])
tmp['variable'] = parts[0]+pd.cut(tmp.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(tmp)), idx], bins=bins, labels=labels).astype(str)

# reshape to wide form
out = (tmp.dropna(subset=['value'])
          .pivot(index=ref_cols, columns='variable', values='value')
          .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   A  B    A1_1   A1_2    A1_3    B1_1   B1_2    B1_3
0  1  1   Apple    NaN     NaN   Apple    NaN     NaN
1  2  2  Banana    NaN     NaN  Banana    NaN     NaN
2  3  3  Tomato    NaN     NaN  Tomato    NaN     NaN
3  4  4     NaN  Apple     NaN     NaN  Apple     NaN
4  5  5     NaN    NaN  Banana     NaN    NaN  Banana
```

Used input:

```
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'A1_1': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Tomato', 'Apple', 'Banana'],
                   'A1_2': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
                   'A1_3': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
                   'B1_1': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Tomato', 'Apple', 'Banana'],
                   'B1_2': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
                   'B1_3': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]})
```